# How do I apply reindex to new data values through filters?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, querydsl

**This is basic_data(example) Output value**

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 163,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "0513_final_test_instgram",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "6uShY3kBEkIlakOYovrR",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "host" : "DESKTOP-7MDCA36",
          "path" : "C:/python_file/20210513_114123_instargram.csv",
          "@version" : "1",
          "message" : "hello",
          "@timestamp" : "2021-05-13T02:50:05.962Z"
        },
      {
        "_index" : "0513_final_test_instgram",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "EeShY3kBEkIlakOYovvm",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "host" : "DESKTOP-7MDCA36",
          "path" : "C:/python_file/20210513_114123_instargram.csv",
          "@version" : "1",
          "message" : "python,
          "@timestamp" : "2021-05-13T02:50:05.947Z"
        }
```

First of all, out of various field values, `only message values have been extracted.`(under code example)

```
GET 0513_final_test_instgram/_search?_source=message&filter_path=hits.hits._source
{
  "hits" : {
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_source" : {
          "message" : "hello"
        }
      },
      {
        "_source" : {
          "message" : "python"
        }
```

I got to know `reindex` that stores new indexes.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html

However, I don't know even if I look at the document.

**0513 attempt code**

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "0513_final_test_instgram"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "new_data_index"
  }
}
```

> How do you use reindex to store data that only extracted message values in a new index?

**update comment attempt**

`output`

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 163,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "new_data_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "6uShY3kBEkIlakOYovrR",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "message" : "hello"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "new_data_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "EeShY3kBEkIlakOYovvm",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "message" : "python"
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to [specify which fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html#docs-reindex-filter-source) you want to reindex into the new index:

```
{
  "source": {
    "index": "0513_final_test_instgram",
    "_source": ["message"]
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "new_data_index"
  }
}
```

Comment: Among the fields, can't you remove the `_index,_type,_id, and_score`

Comment: Is there any way to save only the _source > message value?

Comment: _index, _type and _id are not part of your document, they are meta fields and they will always be there. You can apply the same filter_path on your target index as you did on your source index.

Comment: Then can't you erase the meta-field value?

I don't understand. Show me the code, please.

How can I see that only the value of the message field is stored?

Comment: Your document goes into `_source` (that's the only content you can influence). `_index` and `_id` are fields managed by ES and you cannot remove them (it would make no sense to do so). However, when you can query your new index like you did with the old one, i.e. `GET new_data_index/_search?_source=message&filter_path=hits.hits._source`

Comment: I understood perfectly. Thank you again.